# dropdownlist of month from the financial year i calculated

Tags: c#, sql

I have the sql code below that calculates financial year, so now i want to use c# to create a webpage for financial year and i have to have a dropdownlist of month from April until March. How do i do that, am confused on how i should implement it.
see the code below.

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME, @end_date DATETIME,@cur_date DATETIME
SET @cur_date= (select getdate())
IF MONTH(@cur_date) IN (1,2,3)
BEGIN
    SET @start_date= CAST( CAST(YEAR(@cur_date)-1 AS VARCHAR)+'/04/01'  AS DATE)
    SET @end_date= CAST( CAST(YEAR(@cur_date)  AS VARCHAR)+'/03/31'  AS DATE)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @start_date= CAST( CAST(YEAR(@cur_date) AS VARCHAR)+'/04/01'  AS DATE)
    SET @end_date= CAST( CAST(YEAR(@cur_date)+1 AS VARCHAR)+'/03/31'  AS DATE)
END
SELECT @start_date AS ST_FI,@end_date AS END_FY
```

Comment: forgive me the way my code is posted, i hope you will understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will need a way to call the query or sp in the asp.net mvc controller.
I will assume you can do that and now have the start and end dates as variables in c#.

Here is some code off the top of my head for the controller:

```
DateTime startdate; //value coming from db
DateTime enddate; //value coming from db

List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
var count = 0;
while(startdate <= enddate)
{
count++;
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = startdate.ToString("MMMM"), count);
startdate = startdate.AddMonths(1);
}
```

Next you will need to add the listItems to your model along with another variable such as selectedMonth for getting back the value of the dropdown selection and return it to your view from the controller.

Finally you would add this to the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedMonth, model.listItems, "-- Select a month --")
```